# Приемлема ли обсценная лексика на сайте?

Tags: обсуждение, faq

Есть вопросы, связанные с обсценной лексикой (например, орфографические или этимологические). Несколько подобных задавались, но в итоге были удалены по этическим соображениям. В Справке говорится *(устар.)*:

> Обсуждение табуированной лексики *допустимо в разумных пределах*.

Предлагаю установить четкие критерии, которые должны выполняться, чтобы *разумные пределы* не были нарушены. Иными словами, нужно решить, когда бранные слова уместны, а когда — нет.

Comment: Что в данном контексте означает `(устар.)`? Справка устарела?

Comment: @NickVolynkin что приводится цитата из старой версии Справки.

Comment: А, справку отредактировали только что, понял. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin подробнее: http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/q/170/178412

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Использовать обсценную лексику в аргументации и в обращении к другим участникам совершенно неприемлемо, тысяча чертей! Это противоречит правилам сайта.

Однако такая лексика является частью языка. Было бы очень странно посвятить сайт вопросам о языке, но запретить спрашивать о каком-то его аспекте. Это как на медицинском сайте запретить говорить о репродуктивных функциях, потому что кому-нибудь вся эта тема покажется пошлой.

На сайте есть все возможности для того, чтобы отделить такие вопросы от прочих,  также для того, чтобы позволить участникам исключить такие вопросы из числа тех, которые они видят на сайте.

Для их выделения достаточно метки [обсценная-лексика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0), которую нужно добавлять к вопросам с матерными словами.

Участники, которые не желают видеть вопросы про обсценную лексику, смогут настроить данную метку как игнорируемую. Это делается в [настройках профиля](https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current):

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате все вопросы, которые отмечены игнорируемой меткой, будут исключаться из общей ленты вопросов. Разумеется, останется возможность открыть такой вопрос по прямой ссылке.

Comment: Но медики могут же обходиться без ху * в и п * зд, пример, кмк, не очень.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian разумеется, они могут обойтись без данных конкретных слов. Но им приходится смотреть на обозначаемые части пациентов и даже в руках держать. Так и с филологией — совсем необязательно выражаться, но рассмотреть с научной точки зрения можно.

Comment: Идея с игнором метки хороша, но в идеале бы эту метку по дефолту новым юзерам ставить. А то пришел человек, и, извините, ах * ел

Comment: @VladimirGamalian можно будет сделать инструкцию отдельным вопросом и пришпилить меткой «важное». По дефолту нельзя, механика сайта не позволяет. Ну и у метки должно быть хорошее описание, объясняющее, что можно и нельзя.

Comment: Не попасть под штраф бы. Какой-то был закон для сми, там даже конфискация вроде была прописана.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian тогда можно вконтакик и одноклассников сразу закрывать, там мата на порядки больше. )

Answer (score 7):

Ерунду, простите, пишете.

Для лингвиста не должно быть табуированных слов.
Не все можно использовать в обсуждении, но обсуждать можно всё.
Не надо путать собственно брань с лингвистикой "околобранной" полемики.
Само слово "обсценный" - лингвистический термин, что говорит о том, что лингвистика эти слова совсем не отвергает как предмет обсуждения.

Т.н. матерная брань - такой же пласт языка, как и всё остальное, в чем-то даже более интересный. Фасмер её не стеснялся. Ко всему прочему, мораль штука переменчивая.

*А так мы до абсурда дойдем. Была байка про китайско-русский словарь... 
какого-то киевского издательства. В китайском х@й - один из самых распространеных слогов.  Откройте китайский разговорник на букву Х - поймете, о чем я.*
*Ну так и вот, с чье-то неумной головы пришла указивка все такие слова заменить на три звездочки. В типографии рады стараться... Половина набора уже готова была, когда спохватились. Не рассыпать же... Ну и вышел словарь с примечанием. ### - читать х"й!*

Насчет спойлера... - А у нас есть вообще такая штука? Мне она как-то не очень и нужна, но не видел.  не знаю, ну если кому-то это очень нравится, пусть будет.
//------
*А вообще меня куда больше беспокоят тенденция нарушения сетевого этикета для серьезных сайтов.
У человека есть ник. Это его официальное имя тут. И чертовски неудобно, особенно новичку, соображать, с кем Галина Аванесова опять фамильярничает. 
Потом "на ты" начнем. Слюни в сахаре. Эксгибиционизмом займемся...*

*Идите в приватный чат, там объясняетесь.*

Comment: Я вроде бы ничего ужасного не писал... Нужно определить "разумные пределы", вот и все. Вы это в ответе сделали, спасибо. (А спорные случаи, поверьте, были. Да вам лучше знать даже.) Спойлеры есть: **>** в начале строки — обычная цитата, **>!** — спойлер (пример в моем ответе).

Comment: Произношение, близкое к  х@й, есть разве что в кантонском диалекте (можно услышать в гоконгских фильмах), но это другой в разговорном отношении язык, его у нас обычно не называют "китайским". Это произношение напрямую не отражается в кантонско-русской транскрипции (самое близкое - "хой/hoi"). Материалы, номинально посвящаемые у нас "китайскому", относятся к языку большинства (путунхуа, mandarin). Действительно, в оригинальной транскрипции Палладия была запись х@й, но это условность в обозначении звуков - она не предназначена для чтения по русским правилам.

Comment: В аналогичном романизированном варианте hui запись -ui сокращённо обозначает произносимый трифтонг, близкий к русскому "-уэй". Поэтому в современном варианте транскрипции Палладия (она осталась для транскрипции имён собственных) отказались от записи х@й с её проблемами и заменили на "хуэй" - ценой удлинения записи на букву.

Comment: @Alex_ander  Я слышал эту байку. Но у меня были знакомые китаисты. Нет там трифтонгов, они вообще не свойственны китайскому))))kitaist.info/kursy/kitayskiy/01-fonetika-zdrav‌​stvuyte.html Диалекты тут ни при чем.

Comment: @Aer Хорошо, хотя разговор - флуд сплошной, можно и не замечать.

Comment: @Aer "Пределы" задаются естественным образом. Брани - нет, обсуждению брани - да. Про "спорные" случаи ничего не знаю.

Comment: @behemotus Иногда на восприятие звука влияет настроенность на ожидаемое, но интересно, что вы услышите здесь для слога hui во всех тонах: https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-pinyin-chart.php Что касается трифтонгов, о них говорится во всех учебниках, включая такого авторитета в фонетике как Спешнев. Китаисты старой советской школы находились под сильным влиянием русской транскрипции. Об этом писала в известном учебнике и г-жа Задоенко, на примере транскрипции "шуй" (shui, вода), мол "всё-таки" (если отбросить настроенность на услышание ожидаемого) там отчётливо слышится дополнительное "-э-".

Comment: @Alex_ander у меня отец знал китайский. Потом, правда, ему пришлось резко изменить род деятельности. И был абсолютно чужд какой-то теории. Говорил, как слышал. Я сужу по тому, что написано китаистами, а не апологетами благонравия. Я ***сам*** ничего не слышал. Со Слешневым спорить не буду, не читал.

Comment: Я немножко знаю китайский и подтверждаю, что hui произносится без 'э'. Мне преподавала язык китаянка со стандартным ханьским произношением, поэтому я уверена. Просто когда говоришь на иностранном или слышишь иностранную речь, не обращаешь никакого внимания на обсценные сочетания звуков.

Answer (score 4):

А может быть, стоило бы **выделить эту тему в отдельную группу вопросов,** подобно тому как существуют отдельные словари ненормативной лексики. Пусть читают и обсуждают те, кому это интересно. А на наш сайт разные люди заходят, школьники в том числе. Мне кажется, не очень этично давать все темы вперемешку, но и совсем отвергать обсуждение обсценизмов  тоже неправильно.

Comment: Мне такой подход тоже нравится. Только как их выделять? Красной метки, как здесь, будет достаточно, на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Может быть, им выделить специальный подраздел в вопросах, например, "особая лексика".  А на других сайтах эта проблема как-то решается?

Comment: Не уверен, что получится создать специальный подраздел, это потребует вмешательства разработчиков. На russian.stackexchange.com (РКИ) такие вопросы довольно свободно обсуждаются, для них есть соответствующая метка — swearing.

Comment: @Aer не рассчитывайте на введение каких-то специальных красных меток на основном сайте. Разработчики наверняка откажутся это внедрять и порекомендуют использовать просто обычную метку. И я рекомендую делать то же самое.

Comment: @NickVolynkin тогда выбор не велик: простая метка

Comment: @Aer да, я в ответе написал, что можно сделать, чтобы никогда (почти) не видеть вопросов с такой меткой.

Answer (score 3):

Несколько подобных вопросов и правда было. Не все они удалены ([Размышление о русском мате](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/9449/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5/9500#9500) и [Непростой деликатный вопрос об одном обсценном слове](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/415978/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-18).) На прошлом ресурсе даже, насколько помню, этот вопрос поднимался, и пришли к схожему с вашим выводу, правда, есть одно "но".

Проблема подобных вопросов скорее психологического плана. Те, кому они интересны, вряд ли нужны ресурсу. Те, кто нужен ресурсу, будут испытывать неудобства, обсуждая подобные вопросы в публичном пространстве. В результате чего авторы вопросов про обсценную лексику подвергались критике со стороны более опытных участников.

Я считаю, что имеет смысл подумать о том, чтобы подобные вопросы перенаправлять В Русский язык для иностранцев, где пользователи в целом более лояльны к матерной лексике, если  модераторы там будут не против.

Comment: Все-таки перенаправлять, да тем более к иностранцам, имхо, не выход. Может, стоит придумать что-нибудь не выходящее за рамки сайта? Все-таки вопросы касаются именно русского языка, и будут заданы на нем, а Russian для вопросов на английском.

Comment: @Aer там много вопросов на русском, без английского дубляжа. На запрос слова из трёх букв, мне выдало 21 результат, часть из которых было полностью на русском. Но в любом случае, это нужно обсуждать с модераторами того ресурса.

Comment: Тем не менее, причин, описанных в Справке, чтобы переносить вопрос, я не вижу. Но ваша мысль понятна.

Comment: Перенаправлять вопросы на другой сайт — опасное дело. Однажды Stack Overflow решил перенаправлять вопросы об администрировании на новый сайт Server Fault. До сих пор мучаются из-за этого разделения. :)

Answer (score 3):

Мне обсуждение обсценной лексики представляется возможным и допустимым, если обязательным условием такого обсуждения будет использование метки "обсценная лексика", как предлагает Nick Volynkin. Запрет на обсуждение этой части языка я воспринимаю как что-то неестественное.

Comment: Метка не исключает машинального просмотра Вопроса (2 строки в шапке и ещё 2 строки текста) в полном или почти полном объёме человеком, который не ожидает засады. Таких здесь подавляющее большинство. Второе, и тоже немаловажное: обязать открывающего обсуждение быть почтительным (указывать метку "обсценная лексика") невозможно, что делает бесполезной настройку запрета на метку.

Comment: Тогда заинтересованным в обсуждении обсценной лексики людям нужно придумать другие способы предотвращения машинального просмотра подобных вопросов, если такие способы вообще могут быть действенными.

Comment: Именно так. Желающим  поговорить «об этом» надо предложить дорожную карту курильщиков табака.

Comment: @shampar вы можете добавить метку в игнорируемые, а также вносить ее в вопросы с матом (хотя мы с МаркИз стараемся это делать сразу же, как увидим)

Comment: Я переживу, а вот другим, гостям в том числе, что делать?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, в контексте научной дискуссии применение обсценной лексики возможно, вне ее — нет. Бранная лексика, несмотря на свою табуированность, является важной частью языка, к тому же многие ее стороны плохо освещены, поэтому наличие подобных вопросов в базе может оказаться полезным.

Возможно, во избежание нарушения этических норм стоит особым образом выделять подобные вопросы, а также применять в них спойлеры (**>!** в начале строки):

> *Пример.*

Comment: Аэрчик, дайте ссылку на "спойлер"! Цитирую: *Спойлер (от англ. to spoil — «портить») — преждевременно раскрытая важная сюжетная информация, которая разрушает задуманную авторами интригу, не даёт её пережить самостоятельно и, соответственно, лишает читателя/зрителя/игрока некоторой части удовольствия от этого сюжета, чем портит впечатление от него.*

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova *спойлер* здесь -- скрытая информация, чтобы получить доступ к которой, нужно выполнить определенные действия: например, навести на плашку курсор.

Comment: Вау! Понил-ни-дурак! Я за  *...в контексте научной дискуссии применение обсценизмов возможно*! С поправкой: более чем возможно. Ибо где же, как не в научной дискуссии. Главное-то - мы ж не обзываемся! ))) Мы глаголем о.

Answer (score 1):

Nick Volynkin говорит: «Такая лексика является частью языка. Было бы очень странно посвятить сайт вопросам о языке, но запретить спрашивать о каком-то его аспекте».

Первое. Справедливо было бы добавить — части народа. Этой частью языка не пользуются дети мудрых родителей и просто многие разумные люди без учёта статуса и пола, не говоря уж об армии воцерковленных и их пастырях.

Второе. Запрещать, согласен, — не наш метод. Но задвинуть в чаты вполне можно. Если человек действительно ищет ответ на свой вопрос, дойдёт и до чата, и до Email; ему не нужно рисоваться, ему не нужен рейтинг, ему не нужно развивать и культивировать эту часть языка, им движет потребность знать.