# Вопросы, которые можно задавать

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Статья Справки "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?" была переработана, так как содержала много ошибок и неточностей. С обновленной версией можно ознакомиться [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), текст также продублирован ниже. Опишите, пожалуйста, предложения по ее улучшению, если они, конечно, есть.

Comment: К вопросу можно добавить метку [meta-tag:справка].

Answer (score 1):

Ниже опубликована сама страница справки. Если вы считаете, что необходимо внести изменения, пожалуйста, предложите вашу правку!

---

**«Русский язык»** — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка.

Мы приветствуем вопросы, связанные с различными разделами языкознания (будь то орфография или пунктуация, синтаксис или грамматика, этимология или лексика), о его истории и современном состоянии.

Пожалуйста, прежде чем задавать вопрос, [проверьте](https://rus.stackexchange.com/search), не спрашивал ли кто-нибудь то же самое раньше.

#### Политика

Воздержитесь от вопросов с явной политический окраской. К примеру, о том, как правильно: в или на Украине — [говорилось](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/46568/%D0%9D%D0%B0-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) уже не раз.

#### Опросы

Вопросы с вариантами ответов допускаются, если вы ищете обоснования в правилах русского языка. Создавать опросы с целью выяснить субъективное мнение других участников не следует.

#### "Что хотел сказать автор?"

Литературные вопросы типа *За что Ромео нравился Джульетте?* или *Почему Лоренцо помог влюбленным?* находятся вне тематики сайта. Если же вас интересуют особенности авторского стиля или, например, значение непонятного слова — задавайте вопрос, вам с радостью помогут!

#### Умозрительные вопросы

Абстрактные вопросы, больше подходящие для расслабленной личной беседы, запрещены. Однако вы можете обсудить их в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/).

#### Домашние задания, сочинения и олимпиады

На сайте не помогают писать сочинения. Если у вас ничего не получается, обратитесь к преподавателю, или для разминки сочините фантастический рассказ на полстраницы. По-честному, здесь не должны помогать и с домашними заданиями. Если вы хотите задать вопрос с олимпиады (а он интереснее хотя бы тем, что сложнее), предоставьте убедительные доказательства о ее окончании.

#### Мат

Использование обсценной лексики вне научного обсуждения, а тем более в общении с другими людьми, — неприемлемо. Если же у вас возник вопрос, связанный, к примеру, с историей или написанием матерного слова, вы можете задать его, обязательно добавив метку "обсценная-лексика". Подробнее об этом — [на Мете](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/178412).

#### Изображения

Постарайтесь не задавать вопросы в виде картинок, если только не нужно привести факсимиле или схему.

#### Переводы

Вопросы, связанные с переводом, не запрещены, но помните: здесь не сервис переводов. Если вы не знаете, как лучше построить переведенную фразу, напишите ее дословный перевод с языка-источника.

#### Другие сайты

Обычно, если вам нужен какой-то ресурс, связанный с русским языком, достаточно воспользоваться поисковой системой. Тем не менее вполне возможно, что вы ищете что-то труднодоступное. В таком случае задавайте вопрос — поищем вместе.

Comment: `Значение одного-единственного слова` – весь параграф мне кажется неподходящим по стилю для справочной статьи. Кстати, в чём его смысл? Что нельзя спрашивать о значении слова, но если хочется, то можно?

Comment: @NickVolynkin что если слово редкое и нигде не описывается, о его значении можно спросить. Кстати, [tag:] в Справке не работает.

Comment: Предлагаю направлять не в привилегии, а непосредственно в основной чат сайта. Вот, разморозил: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23242/

Comment: Про последний параграф: всё равно стиль разговорный, он подходит не для справки, а для реплики персонажа литературного произведения.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это справка из бородатых годов, еще со старой платформы. Вполне вероятно, что ее стоит очень сильно изменить.