# Скрыть непристойные вопросы на главной странице: проголосуйте за инициативу

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Безусловно, на нашем сайте уместно обсуждать *любую* лексику. Однако важно помнить, что и ребенок, и любой другой человек, которому противны неприличные слова, по умолчанию видит все вопросы на главной странице. В связи с этим я выдвинул инициативу ввести специальную настройку, которая позволит:

- скрыть обсуждения с меткой [обсценная-лексика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) для всех посетителей, которые не согласились на просмотр такого контента (см. ниже);
- ввести опцию, позволяющую активировать отображение подобных вопросов.

Чтобы предложение было претворено в жизнь с большой вероятностью, нужно проголосовать за вопрос здесь: [Profanity on the main page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324719/379531).

Пожалуйста, сделайте это (если у вас нет аккаунта на сайте по ссылке, создайте его с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу), если вы согласны с идеей.

Comment: Обсуждение по теме: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/156/178412.

Answer (score 2):

Я почитал тред на MSE и не понял, почему это проблема?

Во-первых, если это просто троллинг, то просто удалять такие вопросы.

Во-вторых, даже ненормативная лексика - это часть языка. На https://ell.stackexchange.com/ принято мат закрывать звёздочками. Если уж вы так беспокоитесь за детскую неокрепшую психику, то можете делать также.

В-третьих, что не так с вопросом? [Какать / kacken и Писать / pissen](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/449057/190033). Вы на MSE написали, что эти слова **obcene**. Но в том же Ушакове я не вижу упоминания того, что это ненормативная лексика.

**UPD:** также рекомендую почитать подобные треды на мете других языковых сообществ, типа такого: [Offensive/NSFW words: what are the boundaries](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/446/315118)?

Comment: Обсценизмы — не только мат, но еще и все непристойные слова. Какать и писать не такие «жесткие», как срать, но употреблять их все равно нельзя (если не речь мамы, не желающей подбирать эвфемизмы).

Comment: @Aer Почему нельзя? Это кого-то обижает? Про жёсткие варианты я бы с вами ещё мог согласиться.

Comment: Не буду ничего приводить; считайте моими наблюдениями. Пиздаб*ла в качестве примера вам будет достаточно?

Comment: @Aer я сейчас конкретно про "какать" и "писать". Не нужно переводить тему.

Comment: Я не могу никак еще прокомментировать указанные вами примеры. И вести дискуссию на два сайта тоже. So see you on MSE if you wish.

Comment: @Aer вам для начала нужно было на мете здесь выяснить, что думает сообщество на этот счёт, а не идти на MSE и продвигать своё личное мнение.

Comment: Выдвигать обвинения некрасиво. А мнение не только мое; почитайте обсуждение об обсценной лексике, пособирайте фидбек...

Comment: @Aer я видел в разных тредах схожие обсуждения тут. Но другие сообщества подобные вопросы обычно стараются на локальном уровне решить, т.к. на MSE люди специфики не понимают. Особенно, когда речь про другой язык.

Answer (score 2):

Оставьте все как есть – без цензуры, без кнопок и настроек. Направление страницы: русский язык. Это всеобъемлющее направление.

Answer (score 2):

Я сам не могу определиться по этому вопросу.

С одной стороны, я поставил в своих настройках "игнор" вопросов с тегом "обсценная лексика", поскольку считаю по умолчанию, что в нашей культуре интерес к этой лексике в основном нездоровый, и вопросы с большой вероятностью будут носить характер троллинга, что хуже самого предмета обсуждения. Это практика.

С другой стороны, по опыту относительно недавнего прошлого, а также других культур, я понимаю, что замалчивание/табуирование чего либо как раз и провоцирует нездоровое отношение, а не улучшает его. Поэтому было бы лучше, чтобы на подобных площадках грамотные и уравновешенные люди демонстрировали обществу правильное отношение к таким вопросам. Это теория.

Поскольку теория и практика у меня разошлись, я предпочитаю воздержаться при голосовании.

Answer (score 0):

я недавно посмотрел видео [Откуда взялся мат? — Научпок - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aehewYF8MQ). там сказано, что такое отношение к матёрным словам из-за того, что эти слова использовали в язычестве, а христианство боролось с язычеством, поэтому с принятием христианства эти слова стали запретны.

вообще, я думаю, что, наоборот, русскоязычным правильнее было бы отказаться от эвфемизмов, а исконно русские слова начать использовать спокойно не только в разговорной речи, но и в науке, в медицине, биологии.

сейчас я прочитал по ссылке на английском, и вспомнил кое-что: но некоторые ругательные слова по своей структуре, вероятно, являются несправедливыми, например слова "**бол", "**еть", (конечно, совместно с их смыслом), вероятно, являются некими "женоневастническими". я не против того, что кто-то будет бороться с такими словами.

ещё я вспомнил про такую вещь как стыд, смущение. я не против этого, так как это считается хорошей вещью по исламу. но, если попытаться логически думать, получается, кажется, нету никакой пользя от эвфемизмов...  если уж кто-то стыдится, может быть лучше сказать что-то типа "та вещь", либо вообще не говорить...

Comment: Эта инициатива не про борьбу с матом, а про ограждение от шок-контента, быть может, не готовых к нему людей. Но спасибо за участие!

Comment: «... с принятием христианства эти слова стали запретны.» Поправлю: общее требование к православным (или идущим к вере и сочувствующим) — не допускать сквернословия вообще. Ну а мат как предмет обсуждения — просто за пределами границ всех мыслимых занятий.