# О непечатных словах и самоограничении

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Известный сообществу вопрос от 14 июля с. г. стал поводом поразмыслить на предмет «почему бы здешнюю ***обсценную-лексику*** не ограничить в её правах на сайте». Статья же из сборника — «Кириллица. От возникновения до наших дней», иногда перечитываемого, — оказалась аккурат в русле того, о чём скажу ниже.

В статье (Л.А. Китаева-Смык. Матерщина и сексуальные инвективы в современной России) утверждается, что в общественном сознании «матершинность» как неконтролируемый процесс эротизации речи в основном направлена на воспроизводство населения. В области физиологии мат способствует вбрасыванию в кровяной ток эндорфинов, имеющих бодрящее и обезболивающее воздействие на гормоны стресса. В критических ситуациях сексуальные инвективы (ругань) у людей вызывают выработку мужских гормонов — андрогенов.

Русский мат — это сугубо мужская речь. На большей части территории страны сексуальная бранная лексика (матерная с названиями физиологического низа тела) позволительна только мужчинам. И «смешные», и бранные выражения знают все, но допустимость их определена статусом говорящего и слушающего. В строго женской среде мат — это проявление неосознанных претензий на мужские роли.  На женщин, подростков и детей матерная брань действует иначе, так как провоцирует превышение андрогенов и приводит к гормональным нарушениям, вред от которых превосходит «интенсивный рекреативный эффект» мантр из ядрёных «мужских» слов.

Говоря о проблеме местного масштаба,— коль скоро матерщина не всем представителям населения сайта полезна, а для кого-то вредоносна и оскорбительна (упомянутый вопрос тому пример: он не о шутках и матерных частушках), желательно, на мой взгляд, дать модератору право запрета ругани — как таковой, так и в качестве предмета обсуждения.

Comment: Ваше высказывание о гендерной принадлежности и допустимости русского мата по гендерному признаку - это наиматерейший сексизм. Было бы здорово если бы этот вопрос был сформулирован в контексте обсуждения проблемы без всех этих совершенно устаревших и ненаучных атрибутов.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Приемлема ли обсценная лексика на сайте?](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: Два раза не о том. Я не автор статьи, и не в проблеме ОЛ на сайте речь, а об исключении матерной угрозы (оскорбления, унижения) как недостойного предмета обсуждения.

Comment: Если речь не о том, тогда зачем эта информация в вопросе.

Comment: Не о том (1 ) «Ваше высказывание о гендерной принадлежности...» и (2) «Возможный дубликат вопроса»

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Известный сообществу вопрос от 14 июля (комментарии)**

(1) У нас разве нет возрастных ограничений по этой теме? Сюда же дети могут зайти, да и не всем взрослым это нравится. **Просто не знаешь, куда глаза девать.** Обсуждать надо, но только на специально отведенных площадках.

(2) На Мете уже обсуждали вопрос о  мате. Пришли к единственному возможному правильному выводу:  на форуме как объект обсуждения он допустим. **Насчёт детей не надо иллюзий:** те, что умеют читать и пользоваться интернетом, всеми этими словами владеют не хуже любого взрослого. Нет такого закона, который бы мог запретить мне употреблять какие-либо слова. **Тут у нас взрослые люди, хватит паники.**

**Мое отношение к обсценной лексике**

Обсуждение этой темы возможно только в закрытой аудитории, тогда можно считать, что лингвисты и энтузиасты русского языка изучают обсценную лексику. Если же это делается в отрытом общественном пространстве, то это уже не обсценная лексика, а обычный мат.

Я попробую выразить свое отношение к теме с привлечением дополнительного материала из СМИ и художественной литературы.

**Материал из Интернета**
https://www.svoboda.org/a/29052247.html

«Меня удивляет, как свободно начинают разговаривать на этом языке **12–15-летние школьники.** В последнее время мат все чаще и чаще можно услышать на улице, причем **от девушек, от детей, от групп школьников**, которые идут и совершенно свободно разговаривают матом.

Да, язык реагирует на атмосферу насилия, на агрессивную атмосферу, которой очень много в обществе.  Конечно, это эмоциональная реакция на эту ситуацию…
**Мат – это ведь выражение скрытой агрессии.** Что такое мат? Это всего несколько слов, которые описывают половой акт **в его насильственной грубой форме** – все, больше ничего за этим не стоит! И то, что в нашем языке это превратилось во что угодно и этими словами можно заменить все остальное, – это, до некоторой степени, такая **гипербола насилия**…»

**Нельзя не согласиться с автором статьи.** Действительно, мат – это как бы ответ на насилие, на боль, на страх, то есть на все беды, которые посылает человеку судьба, проверяя его на прочность.  Так мы выражаем несогласие, непонимание,  даем негативную оценку миру, который враждебен нам.

Но разве это нормально?  Разве это учит нас любви, добру,  благодарности за наше рождение,  разве соединяет с природой,  возвышает душу. Нет, это путь в низкие энергии, в полную бездуховность.

**Энергетика матерных слов настолько сильна**, что достаточно самых **простых выражений**, чтобы почувствовать  метафорическую оценку ситуации, выразить отношение к чему-либо.  Но сейчас мат будто вырвался на свободу, это уже **не метафора, а сам язык,** он изнутри разрушает нашу речь. Грубые, жесткие слова  убивают  в человеке способность к многогранному и тонкому восприятию действительности.

**Из романа Б. Акунина «Сокол и Ласточка»**

«В деревянном загоне сидели рабыни… Черные сбились в кучку, а белая трясла клетку и бранила ужасными словами своих немногочисленных слушателей. Словарь у нее был неисчерпаемый,  фантазия изощренная. Моряки внимали **с восхищением,**  а подросток шевелил губами, стараясь побольше запомнить». … Марта как раз закончила перечислять напасти, ожидающие брюшную полость слушателей, и нацелила свой гнев ниже».

А теперь несколько слов о персонажах этой сцены.

«Корабль в море – это образ всего человечества, окруженного пустотой и ужасом Вселенной. Притом образ мрачный, не согретый теплом любви, ибо здесь мужчины оторваны от лучшей части своего бытия – **жен, детей, матерей**… Корабельный экипаж бесприютен и безнадзорен,  это плавучий вертеп всевозможных грехов и злых помыслов».

… Бунтарка сидела на палубе и грозила кулаком. .. «Вам что-нибудь нужно?»   –  «Мне нужно, чтобы налетел хороший шквал и швырнул эту поганую лохань на рифы. Там такие острые скалы! Никто не спасется!»

Отец Марты был рыбаком. Когда он погиб,  мать продала ее в публичный дом, чтобы прокормить остальных малышей. Сколько ей лет? Скоро семнадцать.

Итак,  мат – это эмоциональный ответ на жестокость и агрессию, и он становится частью нашей жизни, будто закрепляя в ней  эти качества.  **Но нам нужно еще большего** – неисчерпаемый словарь, неистощимость фантазии, **обсуждение** всего этого под маской интереса к русской грамматике.

Comment: Соглашусь с каждым словом. Что же до «единственного возможного правильного вывода», так я курсе. Но в осознании этого милосердного жеста всё-таки призвал бы исключать (удалять на корню) поступающие вопросы о выражениях с матерными угрозами, по типу того, как в комментариях и обсуждениях осуждаются — по правилам форума — некорректные высказывания участников.

Comment: в вашем ответе вы сказали, что "мат, это уже не метафора, а сам язык". В этом сообществе мы вроде бы и интересуемся языком, во всех его проявлениях. Раз мат сейчас неотъемлимая часть современного русского языка, значит можно его обсуждать, безотносительно к отношению к этому явлению как таковому. Разве нет?

Comment: @Anton Menshov Мат — часть устной речи, не язык. Мата, обособленного от речи, не бывает. Поэтому, если не обольщаться, он — слова. Это его статус.

Comment: @shampar мне кажется, вы путаетесь в понятиях. Противопоставление устной речи языку я встречаю в первый раз.

Comment: @Anton Menshov Я не против обсуждения, обсуждайте, если вам это интересно, но в отдельном кабинете. Если же общество категорически против и хочет обсуждать это прилюдно, то хотя бы звездочки ставьте, уважайте людей с другим мнением, пусть их и меньшинство.

Comment: @Sharon ваше мнение я уважаю, но с ним не согласен, также как и с направлением в отдельный кабинет. В настоящий момент, на всех известных мне сайтах SE -> ограничение есть лишь на употребление таковых слов в названиях, но не в самих сообщениях. Разумеется, если их употребление внутри сообщения необходимо - в нашем случае, в "лингвистических" целях.

Comment: @Anton Menshov Хорошо, тогда придется  выйти мне. Кажется, я могу как-то избавиться от тем по этой метке. В любом случае я высказала свое мнение, для меня очень важно, чтобы его услышали. Как знать, возможно, оно кому-то покажется убедительным.

Comment: @Sharon к слову так, на мой взгляд, вы выбрали отличное решение. И если вдруг какой-то из таких вопросов не отмечен меткой "обсценная-лексика", то это должно быть незамедлительно исправлено. -> справа, есть блок "игнорируемые метки", где вы можете легко добавить эту метку в ваш список игнора.

Comment: @Anton Menshov Спасибо, теперь я уверена, что моя проблема решена. Но остались вопросы, на которые у меня так и нет ответа. Или есть такой ответ – «Тут у нас взрослые люди, хватит паники!».  Так очень «вежливо и понятно» объяснил ситуацию один из энтузиастов  русского языка, он же большой любитель обсценной лексики. Возможно, вы поможете мне разобраться.  (1) У нас есть закон, по которому доступ к подобным материалам ограничен возрастом 18+. Он касается всех СМИ (средств массовой информации).  Одни ресурсы приравниваются к СМИ, а другие нет.

Comment: Надо думать, что наш форум не приравнивается к СМИ, а какой у него тогда статус в этом отношении? 

(2) Известный вопрос от 14 июля целую неделю находился на первой странице, потом появился еще один подобный вопрос. Но вот как выглядит наше приглашение в Сети:  «Русский язык — это сайт вопросов и ответов для лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка. Присоединяйтесь к сообществу. Любой может задать вопрос. Любой может ответить».  И люди заходят, в том числе школьники  10 – 11 классов, при этом они сразу видят первую страницу. Это нормально?

Comment: И еще меня удивляет странный ажиотаж вокруг вопроса (сразу же 6 голосов автору, 6 голосов отвечающему, у нас такое не часто случается). Будто слетелись голодные голуби, которым крошек насыпали (извините меня за метафору). Просто мне показалось, что, может быть, не так много мест, где это разрешается обсуждать. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461436/Правильное-склонение-слова-хй/461438#461438

Comment: @Sharon мое оценочное суждение, что это плохой закон. Но до моего оценочного суждения никому в принципе нет дела. Этот форум к СМИ в данный момент не приравнен, кроме того, он, в отличии от большинства русскоязычных ресурсов, принадлежит иностранной компании, которая чихать хотела на законы РФ. Что будет, если РФ решит попытаться применить свои законы (необязательно касательно мата) к SE - вопрос открытый, но я не очень вижу рычагов воздействий, кроме очередной блокировки.

Comment: По поводу школьников 10-11 классов. На мой взгляд - абсолютно нормально. Дети младше 13 лет отсекаются правилами SE. Дети старше уже действительно интересуются обсценной лексикой и, на мой взгляд, такие вопросы часто их интересуют. Во всяком случае меня 13-14 летнего, очень интересовали. Не вижу в этом ничего плохого. 

Опять же, я исхожу из позиции, что такие вопросы и многочисленные ограничения РФ (мат, различного типа "пропаганда", оскорбление чувств) - это отвратительно и плохо. Если исходить из позиции что это как минимум нормально, то и выводы будут другие.

Comment: Ну а по поводу конкретного вопроса: я бы беспокоился почему другие вопросы не вызывают ажиотажа. На обсценную лексику всего 25 вопросов из почти 20000, и слабо верится, что эта пропорция сильно изменится. Ну зададут еще десяток в этом году, и все. Особенно если это разрешено и нормально воспринимается, отсекаются тролли - и остаются действительно интересующиеся.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш подробный и обстоятельственный ответ, теперь мне все понятно. Значит, мы на «островке свободы»? Что ж, немного необычно, но я не возражаю. В любом случае было приятно с вами познакомиться, несмотря на наши разные мнения.
И тут я подумала: «Если уж мы теперь знакомы, то не могу ли я воспользоваться этим?» Вы свободно владеете русской письменной речью, но мне интересно, как вы ставите знаки препинания – по правилам или как-то иначе?  Дело в том,  что эта та тема в русском правописании, которая меня очень интересует.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111673/discussion-between-anton-menshov-and-sharon).

Comment: Вы, вероятно, правы. Я на форуме уже более 4 лет, но ни один человек с желанием «хорошо понимать» так и не нашелся. Вот такой я «свободы сеятель пустынный», потерявший  «только время, благие мысли и труды».