# Давайте установим пределы разумного!

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

По похожему поводу уже было [обсуждение](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5). Но я задаю новый вопрос, ведь я хочу внести предложение.

Дело в том, что есть цитата из справки (она приведена ещё в предыдущем обсуждении):

> Обсуждение табуированной лексики допустимо в разумных пределах.

К сожалению, разумных пределов так и не установили. С меткой [обсценная-лексика](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0) есть вопросы с матерными словами.

Примеры:

- [Раз](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461610/%d0%95%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%95%d0%b1%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81)
- [Два](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/461436/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d1%85%d0%b9)
- [Три](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445778/%d0%a1%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%83%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)
- Есть ещё

Предлагаю уже установить пределы разумного и удалить все вопросы с матерной лексикой (именно с матерной, а не все вопросы с обсценной лексикой.

**P.S** Такое предложение [уже вносилось в качестве ответов](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5/159#159), но не было реализовано и всё-таки предложеия на мете принято оформлять вопросами.

Comment: Я все-таки считаю, что это был уже достаточно обсуждено. Более того, выработаны требования к подобным вопросам. Предложение за сим отклоню (в одностороннем порядке, конечно, не слишком хорошо — но на то есть указанные причины).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А каковы причины того, что вопросы с матом не должны приниматься и должны быть удалены? Сайт посвящён русскому языку, мат — это его часть, вопросы о нем, соответственно, задавать можно, так же, как и давать соответствующие ответы. Главное — не использовать мат по назначению и соблюдать [нормы поведения](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).